# Remove Unwanted Rotation of video when merge audio With Video Using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, video-editing

Actually I want to overwrite Audio Using  Recorder Audio file into Recorded Video File.For That I am Using **FFMPEG** Library Project from [this Link](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java)

**Issue:**
When I capture video in **Portrait mode** and then merge video with recorded audio merging is working fine but the problem is Video is rotate 90 Degree and then merging is work.I don't Want to rotate video I want to do merge Only.

if I capture video in Landscape Mode Then Merging audio is Working Fine.

Below Currently FFMPEG Command is Used for merging Audio with Video File

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 OutputFile.mp4
```

And I Have Tried Using Below Commands also but it's Not working

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  -vf -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 OutputFile.mp4
```

And

```
ffmpeg -y -i Video.mp4 -i Audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0  -vf -metadata:s:v:0 translate=1 OutputFile.mp4
```

And I have Trying othe possibility also but its not work for me.

Any Help Would be Acceptable.

Thanks In Advance

Log cat is displaying below

```
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.informer.favoraid/app_bin/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 
built on Feb  7 2015 21:39:25 with gcc 4.6 20120106 (prerelease)
configuration: --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/home/josh/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/home/josh/android-ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -fPIE -pie' --extra-ldflags='-L../x264 -fPIE -pie' --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/files/MP4_FAV20151002_105039_1099425693.mp4':



 10-01 17:15:20.056: I/System.out(6526): sxCon> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 
'/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/files/MP4_FAV20151001_171355_-1450037636.mp4':

  Metadata:
     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
     compatible_brands: isommp42
     creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
   Duration: 00:00:04.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15488 kb/s
     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 16004 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
     Metadata:
       rotate          : 90
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
       handler_name    : VideoHandle
     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/Audio_Recording.mp4':
   Metadata:
     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
     compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
  Duration: 00:00:05.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 18 kb/s
     Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 12 kb/s
     Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
       handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.informer.favoraid/OutputFile.mp4':
   Metadata:
   :     major_brand     : mp42
     minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
     encoder         : Lavf54.6.100
     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (![0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 16004 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
     Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
     creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:44:06
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (@[0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, 12 kb/s
     Metadata:
       creation_time   : 2015-10-01 11:45:13
       handler_name    : SoundHandle
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 frame=  138 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    9008kB time=00:00:04.57 bitrate=16141.8kbits/s
```

Comment: You omitted the version and configure info from the console output.

Comment: please check i have added ffmpeg version and configuration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866706/ffmpeg-unwanted-rotation may be useful. Also try latest ffmpeg maybe a bug was fixed? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4560

Comment: `ffmpeg version 0.11.1`: old and unsupported. Try a build from current git master.

Comment: I Have download project from https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java can you please help me to compile and proceed further.

Comment: 1) install git on your pc 2) git --recursive https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java.git run this command on your command promp 3) GOTO external/android-ffmpeg
./configure_make_everything.sh double click on  configure_make_everything.sh and import this poject in your project as a library project